# What's the default value for maven-surefire-plugin's forkedProcessTimeoutInSeconds?

Tags: java, maven, maven-surefire-plugin

`forkedProcessTimeoutInSeconds` can be set to `0` in order to prevent forked test VMs from being assumed dead after the specified time. What's the default value for this property?

[The documentation doesn't specify it](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#forkedProcessTimeoutInSeconds), the XML autocompletion in NetBeans says `undefined` which doesn't make sense because only setting it to a specified value or `0` does. [A superficial look in the code](https://github.com/apache/maven-surefire/blob/master/maven-surefire-plugin/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/surefire/SurefirePlugin.java) shows that the value must be set outside the class where it's defined.

It's not overly important to figure this out, I more want to make sure that I'm getting the forking process right and can suggest improvement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `forkedProcessTimeoutInSeconds` is a primitive int it will default to 0 itself. Any value > 0 set via the properties will cause the `ForkClient` to set a timeout of that value in seconds.

> `<forkedProcessTimeoutInSeconds>`
> Kill the forked test process after a certain number of seconds. If set to 0, wait forever for the process, never timing out.

Source: https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#forkedProcessTimeoutInSeconds